# nodejs expressjs result.end() not sending result for a POST request if invoked from a callback

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express

I have an express app that handle a post request that looks like this (coffeescript)

```
#Handle CSV Uploads
app.post '/upload', (req, res) ->
  res.setHeader 'Content-Type', 'text/json'

  if !req.session.user?
    res.json
      success: false
    return

  if !req.files.files? || !req.files.files.length
    res.json
      success: false
      message: 'No Files Uploaded'
    return

  file = req.files.files[0]

  if file.mime is not 'text/csv'
    res.json
      success: false
      message: 'Invalid Upload Type'
    return


  #Find IDs of all shippers referenced in this csv
  client_shippers_ids = []
  chainer = new Sequelize.Utils.QueryChainer

  csv()
    .from.stream(fs.createReadStream(file.path))
    .to.path('/tmp/tempcsv.out')
    .transform((row) ->

      return row

    ).on('record', (row, index)->

      chainer.add DB.Order.create
        po_num:      Math.random() + ''
        description: Math.random() + ''
        requested_by: ''
        received:    false
        status:      'Purchase Order Received'

    ).on('end', (count)->
      console.log 'end'
      console.log count
      chainer.run().success () ->
        console.log 'chainer fin'
        res.json #<----- This part does not send
          success: true
          message: 'complete'
    )
```

Specifically this call

```
res.json #<----- This part does not send
              success: true
              message: 'complete'
```

Does not return anything. Is res.end() being invoked before this?

Comment: But `chainer fin` does get logged, right?

Comment: @robertklep, yeah I do see 'chainer fin' logged in my console

Comment: And when you say "doesn't return anything", does that mean the response is empty? Or does the request hang, or give an error message? Because by the looks of it, it should work just fine.

Comment: Yeah response is an empty string, I confirmed it with curl, I agree it's weird

Comment: What if you change `res.json` to `res.send`? Also, what happens if you put the `res.json` command (followed by `return`) right at the top of your handler (just to make sure that there's not some middleware filtering away your response). If you don't get an error on the Node-side, `res.end()` hasn't been called yet (otherwise you would have gotten an error).